# What is the difference between this angularjs app and this similar module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I googled for ng-draggable because I am interested to implement some drag and drop feature in angularjs.

I discovered these 2 links.

http://codepen.io/helpme/pen/GprYKL

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
  <head>
    <title>ng-draggable</title>
```

Another link is an official module from AngularJS.
http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngDraggable

Is the codepen implementation of drag feature different from the ngDraggable module in AngularJS? Can ngDraggable module be made to do the same stuff? If not,  can one combine the codepen implementation with ngDraggable module without causing conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngDraggable is not official Angular plugin, it hosted on GitHub not in [this](http://github.com/angular/) project group.
You can use any implementation of this directive, also I recommend see [Dragula](http://bevacqua.github.io/angular-dragula/).

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted. Dragula actually looks better than ngDraggable. The dragging feels better. But can Dragula be used to implement the dragging on icons like in http://codepen.io/helpme/pen/GprYKL ?

Comment: I don't know. But, you can copy code from pen and use it.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing it now. It is the first time I am using a angularjs directive. I can just copy the directive.